# Php regex preg_replace named capture not working

Tags: php, regex, regex-group

I want to perform a preg_replace on the string and return the named capture as well but the named capture is not showing.  Below is what I have done...

```
string = "{hello}/{world}"

string = preg_replace("/\//", "/\/", string)

string = preg_replace("/\{[a-z]+\}/", "(?P<\1>[a-z-]+)", string)
```

The above is expected to become:

```
(?P<hello>[a-z-]+)\/(?P<world>[a-z-]+)
```

But I'm only getting:

```
(?P<>[a-z-]+)\/(?P<>[a-z-]+)
```

The named capture not appearing.

**Edit**

I'm getting:

```
(?P<{hello}>[a-z-]+)\/(?P<{world}>[a-z-]+)
```

if I change the

```
\1
```

to

```
\0
```

**More Debugging**

The problem is with the < > in the replacement pattern, if I remove them the \1 works fine, but how do I make regex see the < > as literals and not regex special characters. I tried preg_quote and escaping them, not working. \< is how I'm escaping them...

Comment: It looks like your `[a-z]+` is not in a capture group.  Try surrounding it with parenthesis.

Comment: I just did that and still not working...

Comment: Tthe \1 inside a double quoted literal is not a backreference. You must put the replacement and regex pattern in single quoted literals. And yes, add a capturing group.

Comment: Still not working...using php 7 on localhost...

Comment: http://ideone.com/gUl4hE

Comment: Does it have anything to do with php version...? Because the same code but different results...

Comment: Does it work for you? And this not the same code as yours.

Comment: No it's still not working

Comment: I'm using the same code but it's not working...

Answer (score 0):

Capture the group before using it:

```
$string = preg_replace("/\{([a-z]+)\}/", "(?P<$1>[a-z-]+)", $string)
//                  here __^  & __^
```